# realtime database does not display data from pzem-004t

Tags: c, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a program to display realtime firebase data sent from nodemcu ESP8266 + PZEM-004T, but the data does not appear in the realtime database, but on the serial monitor Arduino IDE it works fine.

My output:

[image]

My sketch:

```
#include <PZEM004Tv30.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "iotmonitor-d8aee-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com" //Firebase url non SSL(https://)
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "C7j...Gid" //Secret Key Database
#define WIFI_SSID "IKWAN_BRILink" //Nama WiFi
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "Orbit121" // Password Wifi

PZEM004Tv30 pzem(12, 13);
float harga_KWh = 1.444; //Biaya per KWh
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
}
 
void loop() {
  float voltage = pzem.voltage();
  float current = pzem.current();
  float power = pzem.power();
  float energy = pzem.energy();
  if (isnan(voltage) ) {
    voltage = 0;
  }
  if (isnan(current) ) {
    current = 0;
  }
  if (isnan(power) ) {
    power = 0;
  }
  if (isnan(energy) ) {
    energy = 0;
  }
  float totalHarga = energy * harga_KWh;
  Firebase.setString("volt", String(voltage));
  Firebase.setString("current", String(current));
  Firebase.setFloat("watt", power);
  Firebase.setString("kwh", String(energy, 1));
  Firebase.setString("rp", String(totalHarga, 3));
  Serial.print("Voltage = ");
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.println("v");
  Serial.print("Current = ");
  Serial.print(current, 2);
  Serial.println("A");
  Serial.print("Watt = ");
  Serial.print(power);
  Serial.println("watt");
  Serial.print("KWh = ");
  Serial.print(energy, 1);
  Serial.println("KWh");
  Serial.print("Harga = Rp ");
  Serial.print(totalHarga, 3);
  Serial.println();
  delay(2000);
}
```